# iframe designmode="on" печать за пределами span элемента

Tags: javascript, html, html5, wysiwyg, frontend

Имеется у меня обычный такой `iframe`, внутри такой же простой текст и для подсветки  каких то участков используется `span` с определенным классом. Но вот проблема, если курсор за последним символом текста в этом `span`, то текст набирается только в него, а нужно что бы набор шел после `span`. Проблему с набором обычных символов решил с помощью создания `span` за пределами текущего и выделение его с помощью `range`, но c пробелом какие то чудеса ...

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Поколдовать можно тут -> http://jsfiddle.net/np7a0cLe/ , ибо здесь код по соображениям безопасности не будет работать вообще ...

```js
$(function(){

    isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
     
    frame = $('#text').get(0);
    frameDoc = isIE ? frame.contentWindow.document : frame.contentDocument;
    frameDoc.open();
    frameDoc.write($('#iframeDoc').text());
    frameDoc.close();
    frameDoc.designMode = "on";
    
    $(frameDoc).on('keydown', 'body', function(event) {
            
        var keyCodesList = [ 8, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46 ], // Список клавиш на которые не нужно реагировать
            selection = frame.contentWindow.getSelection();

        if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, keyCodesList) == -1) {
            // Если Node уже помечен как невалидный (родитель редактируемого элемента не body)
            if (selection.isCollapsed &&
                selection.anchorNode.parentElement != document.body &&
                selection.anchorOffset == selection.anchorNode.length) {

                var curRange = selection.getRangeAt(0),
                    range = document.createRange(),
                    Span = document.createElement('span');

                Span.innerHTML = "&nbsp";
                $(Span).insertAfter(curRange.endContainer.parentElement);

                range.selectNode(Span);
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.invalid {
    background-color: #CC7777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Iframe:<br />
<iframe id="text"></iframe>

<textarea style="display: none;" id="iframeDoc">
    <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
        body {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
          font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Arial', sans-serif;
          font-size: 13px;
          line-height: 26px;
          }
        .invalid {
          background-color: #CC9999;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body contenteditable="true"> Какой то текст <span class="invalid">(-blabla-)</span></body>
    </html>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Выход найден. Пробел нужно расположить внутри создаваемого span и указать ненулевую позицию для каретки, selectNodeContents для этого тоже не подходит. Проблема состоит только в том, что добавляется лишний пробел.

```
$(function(){

isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;

frame = $('#text').get(0);
frameDoc = isIE ? frame.contentWindow.document : frame.contentDocument;
frameDoc.open();
frameDoc.write($('#iframeDoc').text());
frameDoc.close();
frameDoc.designMode = "on";

$(frameDoc).on('keydown', 'body', function(event) {

    var keyCodesList = [ 8, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46 ], // Список клавиш на которые не нужно реагировать
        selection = frame.contentWindow.getSelection();

    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, keyCodesList) == -1) {
        // Если Node уже помечен как невалидный (родитель редактируемого элемента не body)
        if (selection.isCollapsed &&
            selection.anchorNode.parentElement != document.body &&
            selection.anchorOffset == selection.anchorNode.length &&
            selection.anchorNode.parentElement.classList.contains('invalid')) {

            var curRange = selection.getRangeAt(0),
                range = document.createRange(),
                Span = document.createElement('span');

            Span.innerHTML = "&nbsp";
            $(Span).insertAfter(curRange.endContainer.parentElement);

            if (event.keyCode == 32) {
                range.setStart(Span, 1);
                range.collapse(true);
            }else{
                range.selectNode(Span);
            }

            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }
});
});
```